# Calculator windows forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, calculator

I'm working on an university project of a windows forms calculator with c#.

Is fully functional, but the question is.

Can I insert numbers in the main textBox without focusing on it. I want it to work like windows calculator and insert numbers without having to click the textbox.

I've try a lot of methods like using the event Key_Press directly on the form but nothing works.

Ps. Is like windows calculator.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advantage".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [Form.KeyPreview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) property to true and handle the Form_KeyPress event.